# Calculate new users subscription amount MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partition

I have a dataset where I need to find out New subscribers revenue.

These are subscribers that are paying either weekly or monthly depending on the subscription they are on.

The unique identifier is "customer" and the data is at timestamp level, but I want it rolled up at monthly level.

Now for each month, we need to find out revenue for only NEW subscribers.
Basically, imagine customers being on monthly/weekly subscriptions and we only want their FIRST Payments to be counted here.

Here's a sample dataset and

```
created            customer                  amount
16-Feb-18 14:03:55  cus_BwcisIF1YR1UlD  33300
16-Feb-18 14:28:13  cus_BpLsCvjuubYZAe  156250
15-Feb-18 19:19:14  cus_C3vT6uVBqJC1wz  50000
14-Feb-18 23:00:24  cus_BME5vNeXAeZSN2  162375
9-Feb-18 14:27:26   cus_BpLsCvjuubYZAe  156250
```

....and so on...

here is the final desired output

```
yearmonth new_amount
Jan - 2018   100000
Feb - 2018   2000
Dec - 2017   100002
```

This needs to be done in MySQL interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to filter the data to the first customer.  One method of doing this involves a correlated subquery.

The rest is just aggregating by year and month.  So, overall the query is not that complicated, but it does consist of two distinct parts:

```
select year(created) as yyyy, month(created) as mm,
       count(*) as num_news,
       sum(amount) as amount_news
from t
where t.created = (select min(t2.created)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.customer = t.customer
                  )
group by yyyy, mm
```

Comment: This is great thanks! But the problem is that it only picks up the minimum create date per each month - so many customers are left out. I want to pick the minimum create date for each customer - considering both variables, any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @PravinSingh . . . I don't know what query you are running, but this query is choosing the minimum create date per customer.

Answer (score 1):

```
   We can have sql subquery for only the 1st payment of the new customer with   
   amount for every month and year

   The query is as follows

  SELECT month(created) as mm,year(created) as yyyy,
  sum(amount) as new_amount
  FROM t
  WHERE t.created=(select min(t2.created) from t t2 where 
    t2.customer=t.customer)
```

Comment: This is great thanks! But the problem is that it only picks up the minimum create date per each month - so many customers are left out. I want to pick the minimum create date for each customer - considering both variables, any ideas on how to do that?